# DNS Inaccessible

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I know this might seem a duplicate but wait!
We have a Windows Server 2012 R2 domain controller, it obviously is a DNS server which hosts one AD-integrated domain. recently, it stopped responding and receiving DNS data a couple of days ago, for an unknown reason. It cannot resolve domain names and cannot reverse-lookup an IP, it means it cannot access root hints, forwarders, other websites and ...
All internet resources are accessible by IP and I can ping root hints and forwarders using their IP addresses.
I've already tried: setting up reverse lookup zones, disabling firewall, disabling IPv6, disabling EDNS0, shutting RRAS down, using an external DNS, rebooting, disallowing suffix appending...
I have no clue about what's going on, until when the RRAS service was active, I could dial the server and resolve all internal FQDNs, but not an external one. This server has one IP address which is completely accessible remotely.
I hope you can help.

**UPDATE: ARP TEST**

```
Interface: 87.236.214.XXX --- 0xc
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  87.236.214.254        64-64-9b-30-20-81     dynamic
  87.236.214.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  224.0.1.24            01-00-5e-00-01-18     static
```

**UPDATE: IPCONFIG**

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : CFS
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : somedomain.co.uk
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : somedomain.co.uk

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9 #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-C2-28-3C-93
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-C7-1E-C3-2A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connectio
n
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-88-B4-CB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::65fa:4976:4508:552d%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 87.236.214.XXX(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 87.236.214.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 302010454
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-C8-30-F4-00-50-56-88-B4-CB

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{A05CB42A-B4DE-4675-B1AB-2FF643A39C8F}:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::200:5efe:87.236.214.163%30(Preferre
d)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 503316480
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-C8-30-F4-00-50-56-88-B4-CB

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C71EC32A-4699-4F87-898D-82BB58445CB5}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter 6TO4_Adapter:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:57ec:d6a3::57ec:d6a3(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 536870912
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-C8-30-F4-00-50-56-88-B4-CB

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C2283C93-6E5F-433C-9775-AA9E9B54F989}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Look into the event log and edit your post to contain relevant lines. Maybe the system tells you what the issue is.

Comment: I've looked into it, DNS has logged no warning or error which could be linked to the situation.

Comment: `I've already tried: setting up reverse lookup zones, disabling firewall, disabling IPv6, disabling EDNS0, shutting RRAS down, using an external DNS, rebooting, disallowing suffix appending` - So this is just a bunch of random stuff that you tried in the hopes that something would fix the problem? How about trying some good old troubleshooting instead? Run nslookup from a client and the server, run a packet capture from a client and the server, run the tests on the Monitoring tab of the DNS server properties, etc., etc.

Comment: @joeqwerty a packet capture? well that seems interesting, I will find a way to do it. However, that was all I knew to do and what I read online, however many of them just solved the other problems we had encountered, but setting up a reverse lookup zone just unexpectedly allowed some inbound DNS request for a couple of minutes. And about nslookup, nothing special is about that, it cannot even find the DNS server. Monitoring tests also gave a failure, but I ignored them as some people with working DNS servers had the same problem.

Comment: Can you provide an ipconfig /all. As I see public IP in your text, but not the internal's one, thus for me it mean you are possibly multihoming the server. If so, your dns is bind to the correct ip?

Comment: @yagmoth555, I'm not sure, I don't think that it's multihomed, we only got one external adapter, note that it's a VPS. DNS is bind to the primary IPv4 address and the other 3 IPv6 addresses, I don't know what those 3 are, and that's what makes me unsure about being multihomed.

Comment: Also another thing that bothers a bit is that `cfs.somedomain.co.uk` which is constantly added as a DNS, I've already added `cfs.`. It has also appended two AAAA records for the external IPv6 address, one for `cfs.` and one for the parent host which are not added by me.

Comment: multihomed = 1 adapter on a network, like on wan, and 1 adapter on another network, like on lan. if so, your dns service is maybe listening to the wan, not lan like its supposed to do.

Comment: @yagmoth555 well, DNS server is listening on all IPs, including the one associated with WAN, but even if that's the problem, what would be up to the DNS client? It cannot contact any DNS server, which would make DNS server fail to contact the forwarders.

Comment: bump? What am I gonna do with this? I added ipconfig results too, but I cannot find any clue.

Comment: nslookup test done as @Rob-d told you to do ? a error in that test mean a router or local firewall blocking the traffic

Comment: @yagmoth555 it just times out, I think I mentioned that before. Also, I even disabled firewall and re-checked, no change.

Comment: Your router might block you then.

Comment: @yagmoth555 It's a VPS, you mean I shall contact the ISP? or the VPS host?

Comment: of course, if nslookup don't pass, it mean the packet cant get out, or cant be received. Your VPS might blame your VM config.

Answer (score 0):

see if you have a dns client problem, open powershell or dos and run the nslookup utility

```
nslookp <enter>
server 8.8.8.8
www.serverfault.com
```

if you receive a reply from google dns then it's not your client and you could try telnet into the DNS server port, this will out rule any network or filrewall issues

```
telnet dnsserver 53
```

flush the dns cache

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

stop and start the dns service

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

check that your arp cache is not poisoned

```
ping dnsserver

arp -a
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as I said, I've already tried external DNS servers but it's the same, telnet is also giving me a blank screen, I flushed the cache, no change, restarted the DNS service, still none, and again as I said before, I can access the whole internet + intranet using IP addresses, including 127.0.0.1, but something that captured my attention was that when I called `ping localhost` it resolved it to IPv6, despite what I did to disable IPv6, it seems alive now. I also checked the ARP and it doesn't seem infected anyway, I will update the question with the results.

Comment: is there any static entries in your host file, C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

Comment: i'm a little confused - is this a DNS server that is not responding to requests or a dns client that can't resolve?

Comment: Q1: I just see a big comment, no host is defined here. :/ (what?)
.. Q2: Both.

Comment: Hey? No one has a solution?